# Samsung Count Badge

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, badge

I developed a count badge for Samsung device. I added badge permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE" />
```

on Android manifest.

On my samsung device (Samsung Note 2, Samsung Note 4, Galaxy Young, Samsung S4) is work, but when published, the client with `Samsung Galaxy Grand I9082`, `Samsung Galaxy Grand I9080L` and `Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 GT N5110` crashes.

This is the log:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.sec.android.provider.badge.BadgeProvider from ProcessRecord{43830aa0 2628:id.co.elevenia/u0a363} (pid=2628, uid=10363) requires com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.READ or com.sec.android.provider.badge.permission.WRITE
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Offtopic here, migrate to http://android.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Badges this library fix the problem

Comment: Hi, how did resolve this issue?Please help me.